# Find which Debian packages are only installed because they are recommended or suggested

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, dependencies

On Debian I can use `apt-get autoremove` to remove packages that are no longer needed, i.e., that are not a dependency of any "manually installed" package. However, this does not remove packages that are merely "suggested" or "recommended" by manually installed packages. How can I find out the list of such packages on my system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also tell `apt-get autoremove` to ignore “Recommends” and “Suggests”:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove -o Apt::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false -o Apt::AutoRemove::SuggestsImportant=false
```

Use `-s` to get a list of the removals this would lead to without actually changing anything:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove -s -o Apt::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false -o Apt::AutoRemove::SuggestsImportant=false
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think this is a much better solution than the one I proposed. Somehow, though, this does not return the same set of packages (it mostly returns more, but it also misses a few that deborphan found).

Comment: The difference in output should be explained by your manual selections: `deborphan` ignores those, so it will find packages you no longer need but that are marked as manually installed. Basically that means you need to periodically review the output of `apt-mark showmanual` and mark packages you don’t explicitly need as automatically installed; then if they are in practice no longer necessary, `autoremove` will suggest their removal.

Comment: Sure, thanks! (In fact, I already have scripts that periodically compare how `apt-mark showmanual` differs from a list that I maintain separately.) However, my point was that the output of your method is not the same as the output of my method even when I take the output of deborphan and specifically remove the manually installed packages (as per the command that I suggested). So I guess there must be some difference in how these two commands compute their output.

Comment: Ah, OK, I see! I’m mostly curious about the extra packages which `deborphan` finds. Perhaps they match the auto-removal configuration in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove*`...

Comment: Here's the list, along with the `aptitude why` of each package:  https://zero.crans.org/?34e8bda1f03afebb#7WoQakPrmoHByhleNwJzQWYNPyiI9BKDZUOO+syF0zo=

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using the `deborphan -n` command, or `deborphan -an`, but paying attention to the fact that this does not seem to really exclude manually installed packages (see [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=867509)), so they have to be filtered separately. I use:

```
comm -3 -1 <(apt-mark showmanual | sort) <(deborphan -na | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d':' -f1 | sort)
```

See also another solution in a [related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108438/aptitude-uninstalling-autoinstalled-packages-that-are-recommended-by-other-pac).