# `sudo apt autoclean` doesn't work; wheras `sudo apt clean` works

Tags: debian, apt

I'm on Debian Bullseye Xfce.  Please find the relevant details of my system below:

```bsh
vrgovinda@krishna:~$ uname -a
Linux krishna 5.10.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.46-5 (2021-09-23) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The version of `apt-get` is as follows:

```bsh
vrgovinda@krishna:~$ apt-get -v
apt 2.2.4 (amd64)
Supported modules:
*Ver: Standard .deb
*Pkg:  Debian dpkg interface (Priority 30)
 Pkg:  Debian APT solver interface (Priority -1000)
 Pkg:  Debian APT planner interface (Priority -1000)
 S.L: 'deb' Debian binary tree
 S.L: 'deb-src' Debian source tree
 Idx: Debian Source Index
 Idx: Debian Package Index
 Idx: Debian Translation Index
 Idx: Debian dpkg status file
 Idx: Debian deb file
 Idx: Debian dsc file
 Idx: Debian control file
 Idx: EDSP scenario file
 Idx: EIPP scenario file
```

When I run `sudo apt autoclean`, it is expected that all the `.deb` files except the most recent versions should get deleted, i.e. the ones which cannot be downloaded anymore, but that doesn't happen in my system. I've posted the samples here below:

```bsh
/var/cache/apt/archives$ ls
libuuid1_2.36.1-7_amd64.deb  libuuid1_2.36.1-8_amd64.deb  lock
libuuid1_2.36.1-7_i386.deb   libuuid1_2.36.1-8_i386.deb   partial
```

Now I run `autoclean`:

```bsh
/var/cache/apt/archives$ sudo apt autoclean 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
```

The contents of the `archives` folder remains as it is:

```bsh
/var/cache/apt/archives$ ls
libuuid1_2.36.1-7_amd64.deb  libuuid1_2.36.1-8_amd64.deb  lock
libuuid1_2.36.1-7_i386.deb   libuuid1_2.36.1-8_i386.deb   partial
```

Surprisingly, `sudo apt clean` cleans out the `archives` folder as expected. It is therefore weird that only the `autoclean` function doesn't work.

```
vrgovinda@krishna:~$ sudo apt clean
[sudo] password for vrgovinda: 
vrgovinda@krishna:~$ cd /var/cache/apt/archives/
vrgovinda@krishna:/var/cache/apt/archives$ ls
lock  partial
```

Results of `apt policy libuuid1`:

```bsh
vrgovinda@krishna:/var/cache/apt/archives$ apt policy libuuid1
 libuuid1: 
 Installed: 2.36.1-8
 Candidate: 2.36.1-8
Version table:
*** 2.36.1-8 500
500 file:/home/vrgovinda/bullseye-deb-files ./ Packages
500 deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
2.36.1-7 500
 500 file:/home/vrgovinda/bullseye-deb-files ./ Packages
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between apt(itude) (auto)clean, …](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/610082/difference-between-aptitude-autoclean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @StephenKitt. I got a clue from his comment. He had asked me to check the output of `apt policy libuuid1` which is as follows:

```bsh
$ apt policy libuuid1
 libuuid1: 
 Installed: 2.36.1-8
 Candidate: 2.36.1-8
Version table:
*** 2.36.1-8 500
500 file:/home/vrgovinda/bullseye-deb-files ./ Packages
500 deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
2.36.1-7 500
500 file:/home/vrgovinda/bullseye-deb-files ./ Packages
```

It shows that my local repository at `/home/vrgovinda/bullseye-deb-files` has the same `.deb` files that are in the `archives` folder.

I had moved all the `.deb` files after each `install` operation, just to have a backup of the downloaded `.deb` files. I also have included `/home/vrgovinda/bullseye-deb-files` as a trusted repository as indicated in my `sources.list` as shown below:

```
deb [trusted=yes] file:/home/vrgovinda/bullseye-deb-files/ ./
#BULLSEYE
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye non-free contrib main  

#BULLSEYE UPDATES
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye-updates non-free contrib main  
#deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib non-free 

# SECURITY
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ bullseye-security non-free contrib main
```

**Answer: When I removed `/home/vrgovinda/bullseye-deb-files` from `sources.list`, `sudo apt autoclean` does its function as expected.**

```
~$ sudo apt autoclean
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Del libuuid1 2.36.1-7 [83.6 kB]
Del libuuid1 2.36.1-7 [84.4 kB]
```

As @cas and @terdon had pointed out, `autoclean` will not delete those `.deb` files that are present elsewhere in some other repository.

Thanks all for your kind inputs.

Comment: Btw, here is one tip: You don't need to move debs from archives to another directory every times you installs a software, instead, you can choose `apt download <pkgname>` to download debs in `pwd` (specifically local apt repository after `cd`ing into that dir) and then install it from there whenever is required :)

Answer (score 6):

You said "*...it is expected that all the .deb files except the most recent versions should get deleted*".   That's not what `autoclean` does.  From `man apt-get`:

> `clean`
>
> `clean` clears out the local repository of retrieved package
> files.  It removes everything but the `lock` file from
> `/var/cache/apt/archives/` and `/var/cache/apt/archives/partial/`.

and

> `autoclean` (and the `auto-clean` alias since 1.1)
>
> Like `clean`, `autoclean` clears out the local repository of retrieved
> package files. The difference is that it **only removes package files
> that can no longer be downloaded**, and are largely useless. This
> allows a cache to be maintained over a long period without it growing
> out of control. The configuration option `APT::Clean-Installed` will
> prevent installed packages from being erased if it is set to `off`.

(extra formatting and bold emphasis added by me)