# How to list packages with no manually installed packages in the dependent tree?

Tags: debian, apt, raspbian, dpkg, dependencies

First, to clarify the terminology:
dependency <-> reverse dependency/dependent

I have `xvt` installed on my headless RPI, and I can't figure out the reason why it's not getting autoremoved.

```
$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

```
$ apt show xvt                                                         Package: xvt                                                                       Version: 2.1-20.3
Priority: optional
Section: x11
Maintainer: Sam Hocevar (Debian packages) <sam+deb@zoy.org>
Installed-Size: 85.0 kB
Provides: x-terminal-emulator
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4), libx11-6
Suggests: menu
Conflicts: suidmanager (<< 0.50)
Download-Size: 36.3 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: no
APT-Sources: http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian bullseye/main armhf Packages
Description: ...
```

```
$ apt-cache rdepends --installed xvt
xvt
Reverse Depends:
```

These don't list `xvt`

```
$ dpkg-query -Wf '${Package;-40}${Essential}\n' | grep yes
$ dpkg-query -Wf '${Package;-40}${Priority}\n' | grep -E "important"
$ dpkg-query -Wf '${Package;-40}${Priority}\n' | grep -E "required"
$ apt-config dump | grep '^APT::NeverAutoRemove::'
```

```
$ apt-mark showmanual
bullseye-default
equivs
pihole-deps
smbclient
transmission-daemon
wireguard-tools
$ apt-mark showhold
```

(I don't love debian's way of using lists and fields besides explicit dependencies, I find it obscure. Hence why I created a bullseye-default metapackage.)

What other mechanism could keep this package from being removed?

Getting back to the question posed, how would I find other secretly redundant packages like `xvt` in this example?

## Requested commands

```
$ dpkg -l xvt
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=====================================>
ii  xvt            2.1-20.3     armhf        X terminal-emulator similar to xterm,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `apt-cache rdepends` output suggests that nothing is keeping your `xvt` package installed, which is odd given your `autoremove` behaviour.

In general, to figure out why a given package is being kept, the best tool is `aptitude why`:

```
aptitude why xvt
```

(you may need to install `aptitude` first).

To list all the packages that don’t have a manually-installed package in their reverse dependencies, run `apt autoremove` in simulation mode, ignoring recommended and suggested packages:

```
sudo apt autoremove -s -o Apt::AutoRemove::SuggestsImportant=0 -o Apt::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=0
```

Note that by default, `autoremove` is imbalanced: recommended packages are installed by default, not suggested packages; but suggestions prevent autoremoval. See [How do recommends and suggests interact with apt-get dist-upgrade and apt-get autoremove?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/447952/86440) for details.

Comment: Very useful answer, thank You! I have suspected that xvt might be a suggested package, but apt-rdepends said nothing suggests it. Aptitude, however, solved the mystery: x-terminal-emulator virtual package is the suggested one, which xvt provides.

Answer (score 0):

> What other mechanism could keep this package from being removed?

You can use `apt-mark hold` to prevent a package from being automatically upgraded or removed.

This would be useful if, for example, another package conflicts with one of the packages depended upon by your `bullseye-default` package.  Marking `bullseye-default` as held would prevent it from being auto-removed (thus causing the packages it depends upon to be candidates for auto-removal if no other package Depends/Recommends/Suggests them).

If you ever needed to upgrade `bullseye-default`, you'd have to do that manually and then remember to run `apt-mark hold bullseye-default` again (as upgrading a package clears the Held status).

BTW, `apt-mark` can also be used to change a package's auto/manual installation status - e.g. `apt-mark auto packagename` or `apt-mark manual packagename`.  It can also be used to show lists of automatically installed and manually installed packages: `apt-mark showauto` and `apt-mark showmanual`.