# why this package is not proposed to me to remove?

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg, deb

As I understand it, if a package is auto-installed and has no other packages depending on it, the system should offer to remove it.

why doesn't this happen in this case?

```
:~$ sudo apt list --installed | grep -i zutty
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
zutty/unstable,now 0.14.0.20230218+dfsg1-1 amd64 [installato, automatico]

:~$ sudo apt-cache rdepends zutty
zutty
Reverse Depends:

:~$ sudo apt autoremove 
Lettura elenco dei pacchetti... Fatto
Generazione albero delle dipendenze... Fatto
Lettura informazioni sullo stato... Fatto   
0 aggiornati, 0 installati, 0 da rimuovere e 0 non aggiornati.
```

PS sorry for italian output console

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`apt autoremove` is more conservative by default than `apt install`; in particular, `apt install` installs recommended packages by default, and ignores suggested packages, but `apt autoremove` takes suggestions into account. (See [How do recommends and suggests interact with apt-get dist-upgrade and apt-get autoremove?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/447952/86440) for details.)

That’s not what’s happening here though. `zutty` isn’t a candidate for auto-removal because it provides `x-terminal-emulator`, and many packages depend, recommend, or suggest that.

The simplest way to determine why a package is being kept is to ask `aptitude`:

```
aptitude why zutty
```

Comment: sorry but i didn't understand the last part, apparently no one depends on zutty

Comment: Packages depend on `x-terminal-emulator` (a virtual package), which `zutty` provides; so `apt` keeps `zutty` to satisfy the `x-terminal-emulator` dependency.

Comment: thz, i know nothing about virtual packages, i will study

Comment: it's quite tricky, 'apt-cache rdepends' do not show that, package detail do not mention that are an implementation of virtual package. and if you have more than one package installed for one virtual package there is not way to undertand that you can free space

Comment: `apt show zutty` shows `Provides: x-terminal-emulator`. `rdepends` doesn’t show enough information for this scenario, yes; you might find `aptitude why zutty` more useful. And yes, it’s not easy to figure out that you can remove packages when multiple packages provide the same virtual package...

Comment: after 17 years of debian usage i discover a new thing thanks to you. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

It *could* be due to changes to the package or dependencies. If a package or its dependencies have changed since they were installed, `apt` might not recognize that they're no longer needed. This can happen if a package's dependencies have changed due to updates or other changes to the system.

You could try to use `apt-mark showmanual` to show all packages `apt` considers as manually installed. If `zutty` is in the list, you can mark it as automatically installed using `# apt-mark auto zutty` and then try `# apt autoremove` again.

If this doesn't work, you could try running `# apt-get autoclean` and `# apt-get clean` to clear out the local repository of retrieved package files, then try `# apt autoremove` again.

Comment: zutty are already installed as auto (you can see it on first command). i done clean and autoclean but nothing changed