# What is the difference between apt purge '~o' and apt --purge autoremove?

Tags: linux, debian, apt

The Debian 12 upgrade guide [recommends](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/arm64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html#obsolete) purging obsolete packages  with the command:

`apt purge '~o'`

What is the difference between this and `apt --purge autoremove`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [obsolete package is defined](https://manpages.debian.org/apt/apt-patterns.7#PACKAGE_PATTERNS) as:

> `?obsolete, ~o`
>
> Selects **packages that no longer exist in repositories**.

A package that was automatically installed (same link) can be selected with `~M`:

> `?automatic, ~M`
>
> Selects packages that were installed automatically.

These are packages that received the [extended state](https://manpages.debian.org/apt/apt-mark.8#FILES) property `Auto-Installed: 1` which happens when a packet was automatically also installed because of dependencies for installing an other package (or were installed with the option `--mark-auto`, or had their extended state changed with `apt-mark`).

A package that can be removed automatically (which has to also be part of the previous result) with `~g`:

> `?garbage, ~g`
>
> Selects packages that can be removed automatically.

will be a package that was automatically installed and has nothing depending on it (including weak dependencies related to `Recommends`, `Suggests` from other packages, also including meta packages this package provides with `Provides`. See [why this package is not proposed to me to remove?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/750882/why-this-package-is-not-proposed-to-me-to-remove) for these details).

In the end, Doing `apt purge '~g'` will by definition do the same as `apt --purge autoremove`, but is not what is recommended to do in the Debian 12 upgrade guide.

One side effect of `apt purge '~o'`, is that any 3rd party package that is not also provided by Debian (or any other source list) that was installed manually using `dpkg -i` or `apt install ./path/to/deb` will match since not found anywhere. For example the proprietary Zoom package is [documented to be installed](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/204206269-Installing-or-updating-Zoom-on-Linux#h_89c268b4-2a68-4e4c-882f-441e374b87cb) with `sudo apt install ./zoom_amd64.deb` and doesn't provide any repository either after installation: this one will always be selected as obsolete. That's "fine" because the upgrade to Debian 12 also [recommends to remove such 3rd party packages](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/arm64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html#system-status):

> 4.2. Start from “pure” Debian
>
> The upgrade process described in this chapter has been designed for
> “pure” Debian stable systems. [...] if you have installed packages from other releases or
> from third parties, then to ensure a reliable upgrade process you may
> wish to begin by removing these complicating factors.