# Are --install-suggests and --no-install-recommends mutually exclusive?

Tags: linux, apt, package-management

Here is an arbitrary example of my attempt to install a package (wine in this example):

```
sudo apt install wine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  fonts-wine libcapi20-3 libodbc2 libosmesa6 libwine libz-mingw-w64 wine64
Suggested packages:
  odbc-postgresql tdsodbc q4wine winbind winetricks playonlinux wine-binfmt dosbox wine64-preloader
Recommended packages:
  wine32
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fonts-wine libcapi20-3 libodbc2 libosmesa6 libwine libz-mingw-w64 wine wine64
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 104 MB of archives.
After this operation, 698 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

From the output there are two categories (presumably optional) called:

- `Suggested packages:`
- `Recommended packages:`

My understanding is that `--install-suggests` will install `Suggested packages` while `--no-install-recommends` will not install `Recommended packages:`

Is my understanding correct?
My confusion and question is (in relation to the output) what exactly does these two options do?

I assume `--install-suggests` will install `Suggested packages` which must mean that `Suggested packages` are not automatically installed, is that correct?

On another side I assume that `Recommended packages:` are automatically installed unless `--no-install-recommends` is specified.

Is my understanding correct and if not how should I use those 2 options in relation to the output?

To add to the confusion these 2 options seem like mutually exclusive due to the fact that one has negative conotation while another has positive conotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options are described in `man apt-get`:

- `--no-install-recommends`:

  > Do not consider recommended packages as a dependency for installing. Configuration Item: APT::Install-Recommends.
- `--install-suggests`:

  > Consider suggested packages as a dependency for installing. Configuration Item: APT::Install-Suggests.

Your understanding is correct: by default, `apt` installs recommended packages, and ignores suggested packages. `--install-suggests` adds suggested packages, and `--no-install-recommends` ignores recommended packages. The options are *not* mutually exclusive.

Those defaults can be changed by editing `apt`’s configuration, using the configuration items mentioned in the documentation above. In fact that’s how the command-line options are implemented: the configuration is loaded from defaults, then updated using the configuration files, and any command-line flags update them again. So `--no-install-recommends` disables `APT::Install-Recommends`, `--install-suggests` enables `APT::Install-Suggests`. Opposite options are also available, `--install-recommends` and `--no-install-suggests`.

See also [How do recommends and suggests interact with apt-get dist-upgrade and apt-get autoremove?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/447952/86440)

Comment: I really appreciate your logic-driven and authoritative answers! this clears everything up, thank you!